# What size to make the stage in Edge Animate for one ipad/iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-edge

I am about to build my very first ipad/iphone app in Edge Animate and port it through PhoneGap Build to the app store.

1. What size do I set the Edge Animate stage to so that the same app will work on both ipads and iphones, 764 x 1024?
2. Do I turn on 'Responsive Scaling' in Edge Animate, and set it to 'Width' (or set to "Both") so that it will scale down for iphones, is that how you get it to work on both?

Thank you